# How to Set Multple Regex Costraints on textbox in ZKOSS

Tags: regex, zk

I have a textbox which should only accept Characters:-for that first regex has been set in constraint and it should not accept some reserved keywords that are A,R,F,U .Since two different constraints are set ,i want user to see the specific message ,for first it should be Illegal Value i.e default zkoss error and when he/she enters a reserved character ,it should show that reserved code has been put.
But somehow the following code doesnt work :

```
 field_code.setConstraint("/[a-zA-Z]/ : {Illegal Value} ,/[^AaRrUuFf]/ : Reserved Code");
```

The output is the first regex works fine but on offending the same `" {Illegal Value} ,/[^AaRrUuFf]/ : Reserved Code"` is displayed as error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it in the zul, but with help of a `SimpleConstraint` you could create this.

Create your own class, and extend `SimpleConstraint`.
Then hold 2 `Matcher` vars for each constraint.
At last, override the Validate method to something like this :

```
@Override
public void validate(Component comp, Object value) {
    if (value != null && value instanceof String) {
        String stringValue = (String) value;
        if (!expression1.reset(stringValue).matches()) {
                throw new WrongValueException(comp, errorMsg1);
        }
        if (!expression2.reset(stringValue).matches()) {
                throw new WrongValueException(comp,errorMsg2);
        }
    } else {
        // do what needs to be done when value is null or not a String.
    }

}
```